# Is there a way to keep internet connections / sockets open after iOS forces app into sleep mode?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I'm developing a Xamarin app that uses location background modes to keep itself awake in the background, scan and report on iBeacons in its range over AMQP, and also make HTTPS requests to a log server.

This all works great, until a sustained period of time where the GPS location does not change and there are no changes to the radio frequency environment (i.e. no new iBeacons introduced, none taken away).

It appears that iOS puts the app into sleep mode (it's a slightly different sort of sleep mode to normal, as background modes are involved, so I don't see an OS callback for this). Moving the phone, or introducing new iBeacons wakes the phone up, but sometimes the app is no longer able to access the internet, using objects that were created before the app was sent to sleep. It appears as if the kernel is closing  sockets.

Any ideas as to how I could diagnose this issue more effectively, or suggestions to how I can keep these sockets open, would be most appreciated.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: You can't keep the sockets open when your app suspends. You need to re-establish the connection when your app receives an event in the background

Comment: You can refer to the link https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html